# How to pass string "Hello #" in EFI Shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, uefi

I hope EFI Shell script will work similar to Linux scripting languages but its not.
Following is my EFI Shell script content,

`MyApp.efi "Hello #"`

Then i run script.nsh, its executing only following content,

`MyApp.efi "Hello`

here # missing, its treating comment entries,
Please help me, I tried with following combinations also

`MyApp.efi '"Hello #"'`

For above content its executing ,

`MyApp.efi '"Hello`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "Hello ^#"
```

You have to escape the # even if it is in a string.  Also, this might not work if you have an older version of the EFI Shell.

Comment: @subrahmanyeswaraswamymurala Would you please mark my answer as correct? Maybe it will unlock some grand privilege for me. :-)